# Clickable Dropdown Menu Items Aligning with Page Object Elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://nigeldurham.github.io/ux/about

The dropdown menu items for this clickable menu are responsive to the "margin-top" of the page's text elements. I've tried z-indexing the navbar contents for them to "float" above the existing content but no variation of this appears to be working.

Any insight here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

'''

```
.topnav {
  position: fixed;
  color: black;
  right: 0;
}

.topnav #mylinks {
  display: none;
  margin-top: -138px;
} 

<div class="topnav">
<div id="mylinks">
<a href="https://nigeldurham.github.io/ux/about.html" style="font- 
weight: bold">about</a>
<a href="https://nigeldurham.github.io/ux/index.html">work</a>
<a href="https://nigeldurham.github.io/ux/contact.html">contact</a>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please paste code here or provide a link to some sandbox, so it would be easier to help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

can you please check below code i have fixed for mobile screen 450px and below .

```
@media screen and (max-width:450px){
div#mylinks {
    margin-top: 0px !IMPORTANT;
}
.topnav {
    top: 56px;
    }
}
```

before 
[image]

Now
[image]